# JPA Many-To-Many Relationship with same DB and extra Attribute

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa, relationship

I need a Many-To-Many Relationship within the same Database. I don't mind creating mapping databases, but I want to have only one Entity in the end.

Let's say I've got a resource which can have many resources (Sub-Resources). What I need is an Resource with the Sub-Resources and also the count of them because one Resource can have x resources.

Essentially, I need this with the extra Attribute of the count of Sub resources needed for the Resource.

```java
@Table(name = "resources")
public class Resources {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    private Collection<Resources> subResources;
    
}
```

To clarify that a bit, at best I would have something like that:

```java
@Table(name = "resources")
public class Resources {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    private HashMap<Resources, Integer /* count */> subResources;
    
}
```

I know how it works with two tables (Resources & Sub Resources) and a mapping type, but I couldn't figure out how to do it as described above, since Resources can be Sub-Resources at the same time.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** I need an extra Attribute in the mapping table where I can set the amount of sub resources as an Integer

Comment: Couldn’t you implement a transient property returning the count of the resources expect the current? subresources.stream.filter(not(o.I’d.equals(this.I’d).count. As the identifier is proxied eager fetch should not be necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I don't need a count of sub resources associated. I need a virtual count of each sub resource

Answer (score 0):

The configuration yo have will work for a unidirectional relationship. There is no technical problem, only you will not be able to specify the multiple parents of a subresource, so in the end it is not many to many.

To make it trully many to many you need another field on the `Resources` class to define the *inverse* side of the relationship; I have added the `@JoinTable` annotation to make the names in the join table explicit, but it is optional if the defaults are good enough for you; I also switched from the vary basic `Collection` to `List`; I would prefer `Set` and you would have to provide `equals` and `hashCode` on the entity. Finally I am always initializing the collection-valued fields (`ArrayList` here; `HashSet` if you go for `Set`), so as to avoid silly `NullPointerException`s or complex initialization code:

```java
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "RESOURCE_SUBRESOURCE",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "resource_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "subresource_id")
    )
    private List<Resource> subResources = new ArrayList<>();

    // the mappedBy signals that this is the inverse side of the relation, not a new relation altogether
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "subResources")
    private List<Resource> parentResources = new ArrayList<>();
```

Use as:

```java
    Resources r1 = new Resources();
    r1.setName("alpha");
    em.persist(r1);

    Resources r2 = new Resources();
    r2.setName("beta");
    r2.getSubResources().add(r1);
    em.persist(r2);

    Resources r3 = new Resources();
    r3.setName("gama");
    em.persist(r3);

    Resources r4 = new Resources();
    r4.setName("delta");
    // won't work, you need to set the owning side of the relationship, not the inverse:
    r4.setParentResources(Arrays.asList(r2, r3));
    // will work like this:
    r2.getSubResources().add(r4);
    r3.getSubResources().add(r4);
    // I believe that the order of the following operations is important, unless you set cascade on the relationship
    em.persist(r4);
    r2 = em.merge(r2);
    r3 = em.merge(r3);
```

**As for the count:** In the question you mention that you want a count of related objects. While specific JPA providers (Hibernate, EclipseLink) may allow you to accomplish this (using a read-only field that is populated by an aggragate query - `COUNT(*) FROM JoinTable WHERE resource_id=?`), it is not standard. You can always do `resource.getSubResources().size()`, but that would fetch all the subresources into memory, which is not a good thing and might in fact be a really bad thing if you call in frequently or there are many sub/parent resources.

I would prefer to run a separate count query, perhaps even for a set of resource ids, whenever I really need this.

Comment: Thank you for your response! This is already very helpful, but won't work for what I need, since I need a count for each sub resource. So for example the resource A has a relationship with the sub resource B and needs an extra attribute on the mapping Table in order to describe the count of sub resources needed for the resource.

Comment: To clarify that a bit, the best case for me, would be to have HashMap<Resource, Integer /* count */> subResources; as a property in the end.